# An old couple kill some young strangers happily

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

**Personal Experience:** This is probably one of the weirdest movies I have ever seen.

**Genre:** Horror

**Production date:** I have seen this movie at least 5 years ago. Obviously produced after 2001.

**Plot:** A group of 5 friends (at least) get lost in some forest (or exploring). And they find this modest house in the middle of nowhere to seek shelter. They find a happy, healthy (apparently) living old couple who give them the best hospitality. The couple invites the group to stay in their house for the night. Few moments later, the movie gets very disturbing, the couple start killing those young people one-by-one in different ways, and they were very happy and calm. They manage to kill them all besides one person who will manage to kill later the old wife.

**How it ends:** The old man goes outside of the house after his old wife is dead. The murderer puts his hands in the sky and shouts "Why God! What did I do to you". Clearly some subliminal message from the director.

Comment: Since you don't mention dolls, I don't think this is it, but it reminds me of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolls_(1987_film)

Comment: Was reminded of Dolls too! But that wasn't really a group of young people and the end is totally different. Also thought of House of Clocks, but both of them are way too old. @georgechalhoub, do you remember the production value? Was it extremely shoddy (shot cheaply with amateur actors) or did it seem to have a reasonable budget?

Comment: @Walt, I don't think the budget was extremely shoddy. I enjoyed the movie and I don't remember the actors being amateur. Otherwise, the movie would not have been stuck in my head. I am 100% sure of the ending if it will help you identify it.

Comment: @georgechalhoub, are you *sure* it was after 2001? I have a very good match in mind, but it's much older than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very strong possibility, but with one difference: [American Gothic](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094642/combined).

**Similarities:** 6 young friends go vacating on an island. After their plane has engine problems, they decide to stroll through the woods and come across the house of a seemingly kind old couple called Ma and Pa and their simpleton family. Ma and Pa give them great hospitality, but the young friends start to disappear one by one, killed in many different ways. Only one survives, and she manages to kill the family and stabs Ma with her knitting needles. When Pa comes home and finds Ma's body, he goes outside and yells at the heavens, renouncing God. The final girl then shoots him in the back.

**Differences:** It's from 1988.

Here's the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLXdVqzHafU). The entire movie is available in [6 parts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA149989350A92FEE) on Youtube; you can see Pa (Rod Steiger) screaming at God in [Part 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIvmd__9rao) around 12:30. The film's also known as *Hide and Shriek* in the UK.

[image]

Comment: You seriously rock! I'm sorry about the date, I was wrong about it. This is 100% the movie I had mind. I'm very curious to know, how you were able to identify it?

Comment: I dismissed it earlier because of the date, but looked it up on Youtube because I couldn't remember much about it and was curious; sure enough, the ending fit.

Comment: For 2 straight days I tried to think of the title, even though I could vividly picture the DVD case and the picture on it (which is actually a nod to a very old painting).  DAMN!